# Calling PowerShell Azure module and creating resource group from C#

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, .net-6.0, azure-powershell

I have the following PowerShell script that 1) installs Azure PowerShell SDK 2) logs in to Azure using the service principle and 3) creates a resource group. I am trying to call this script from C# .NET 6 but I am getting this error:

```
New-AzResourceGroup -name $recoveryResourceGroupName -location $locat …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'New-AzResourceGroup' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I think it's not running the PowerShell script code at all.

Note that the actual script does a lot more than just creating a resource group, but this is just an example.

```
// The difference between CreateDefault and CreateDefault2 is that
// CreateDefault includes engine snap-ins, while CreateDefault2 does not.
var initialState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
using var ps = PowerShell.Create(initialState);
var results = await ps.AddScript(@"
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $applicationId = """"
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $secret = """"
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $subscriptionId = """"
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $tenantId = """"

# Install Azure Powershell modules
Write-Output "Installing Modules..."
if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name 'Az*') {
    Write-Output "  Az Already Installed"
} 
else {
    Install-Module -Name 'Az' -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
    Write-Output "Installed AZ"
}

# Import Azure module
Import-Module 'Az'

# Login to azure using credentials from the KeyVault
$secretAsSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secret -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($applicationId, $secretAsSecureString)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId

# Select Right subscription
Set-AzContext $subscriptionId

New-AzResourceGroup -Name 'TestRg123' -Location 'eastus2euap'
").InvokeAsync();

foreach (PSObject outputItem in results)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(outputItem);
}
```

**UPDATE #1**:
I updated the script and added `-AllowClubber` to make Az is installed but this is what I am getting in the output:

[image]

I think `Az` is not getting installed and for some reason it think Az is already installed

And then

```
New-AzResourceGroup: 
Line |
  97 |  New-AzResourceGroup -name $recoveryResourceGroupName -location $locat …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'New-AzResourceGroup' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

**UPDATE #2**: I modified the PowerShell script to unconditionally install the `Az` and I am still getting the same error that `New-AzResourceGroup` is not defined

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Azure.ResourceManager nuget to make resources from c#? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-dotnet-manage-resource/blob/main/Program.cs

Comment: The original PowerShell script is very large. 1000+ lines of code that uses azure PowerShell sdk

Comment: Is it possible that it's importing the module from a different location then it's installing? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-7.2#module-and-dsc-resource-locations-and-psmodulepath

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar error when i am using command

```
New-AzResourceGroup
```

Then i have used Azure cli commands then i get the resource group created in azure

My powershell script(Updated your script):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Management.Automation;

var initialState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
initialState.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;

using var ps = PowerShell.Create(initialState);
var results = ps.AddScript(@"
Install-PackageProvider -Name Nuget -Scope CurrentUser –Force

Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet -Scope CurrentUser –Force

Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

# Import Azure module

Import-Module 'Az'
Import-Module 'Az.Accounts'
Import-Module 'Az.RecoveryServices'

az login

try {
    az account set --subscription ""XXX"
    az group create --name rithDemo --location eastus
}
catch
{
    $string_err = $_ | Out-String
    Write-Output ""Failed to run test $testname because $string_err""
}
").Invoke();
```

XXX- Subscription name

rithDemo- resource group name

- In script I have first login into azure using `az login`. Then you will be redirected to azure login page there you can login.
- Then I set the subscription using `az  account set` command
- Then I created a resource group using `az group create`
- Also added AllowClobber in script
  By this process the resource group got created.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Was the Powershell script above written as a Azure function or was it a genuine C# code, invoked from VM or PC?

Answer (score 0):

Check your powershell version and try to download latest:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

In your script you should be able to use:

```
Import-Module Az.Resources

#Just in case

Az Upgrade
```